How to save the result of a query in Flink's SQL CLI
I'm running SQL queries using Flink SQL CLI,
and I need to save the result of queries like "SELECT ...NOW()...FROM ..."
which include timestamps.
I want to keep the timestamps when NOW() is evaluated and not trigger re-evaluation.
How can I save a copy of the result in a local file using only SQL CLI?
I tried to run
INSERT INTO tableTwo select ... , Now(), ... from tableOne

but from the flink web monitor, I found that the job for this query never finishes executing. I'm wondering if there's another way to keep the result of
SELECT ..., Now(), ... from tableOne

without embedding the queries in a Java/Scala program and using solely the command line.

What execution mode is set in your session?

Hi @GeoJim, I’m using the default streaming mode

Hi @Layke, are the sources bounded or unbounded?  If tableOne is an unbounded source, then that query will run forever.
If you want the query to terminate, you'll need to bound the data source.  With that done, you can run the query in streaming or batch execution mode.
If you switch to batch execution mode, queries with unbounded sources will fail.  That could be one way to show you if you have configured things to be bounded or not.

Thanks, @GeoJim! tableOne is unbounded. I was trying to use it to monitor files in a folder, so I created the table with: WITH ('connector' = 'filesystem', 'path' = '...', 'format' = 'csv', 'source.monitor-interval' = '1 ms');
What I want to do is to capture the time when new data is added to the folder. I'm approximating the time using SELECT ...NOW()... If the query that never ends is not working, do you know what else I can try to sink the results of the SELECT into another table or save the result? Thanks!!

I'm using another terminal to add new files to the folder and running SELECT in SQL CLI. The results are shown in real time, but I'm not sure how to save them since I don't want to re-evaluate the NOW() function.

Ah, have you tried adding a proctime() column to the table?
I believe that'd give you "now()" when the new record is available.  You'd be able to write an INSERT INTO queries which stores the results of the polling into another table.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/time_attributes/#processing-time

Inserting data into a table using a Kafka connector works as follows: First, I run the consumer, directing the output to a file. Then, I perform the insertion using Flink SQL, and the results can be saved locally.
